# How one can define a similar distance for the interval $(0,1)$ to be complete

Tags: general-topology

We know that, $ℝ$ is complete, whereas an open interval is not, when
one uses the usual metric $$d(x, y) = |x − y|$$

If, we define a metric on the open interval $(-π/2,π/2)$ by $$g(x, y) = |\tan x − \tan y|$$
then it is known that this unusual metric space is indeed **complete**.

**My question is**: How one can define a similar distance for the open interval $(0,1)$ to be **complete**.

Comment: What do you mean by similar?

Comment: @carmichael561: similar method

Comment: How about replacing $\tan x$ with $\tan(\pi(x-\frac{1}{2}))$ then?

Comment: @carmichael561: can you proves that this is a complete distance

Comment: It should be essentially the same proof as for $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: @carmichael561: Thank uou very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general method that works in any complete metric space: suppose $O \subset X$ is open in a complete metric space $(X,d)$. Define $f(x) = d(x, X\setminus O)$, which is (by standard facts) continuous and $>0$ on $O$.

Then $d'(x,y)  = d(x,y) + \left| \frac{1}{f(x)} + \frac{1}{f(y)} \right |$ is a complete metric on $O$ that is equivalent to the restriction of the metric $d$ on $O$. This is a fun exercise.

Comment: This is possible if $X$ is not the closure of $O$.